# Why does epoll use a red-black tree to manage file descriptors rather than a hash table?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The linux system call [`epoll_ctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html) (at `fs/eventpoll.c`) uses a red-black tree known as the interest list to create, remove, or modify interest in events of a file descriptor. The interest list [is not searched by `epoll_wait`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474602/does-epoll-do-its-job-in-o1), which rather [waits for callbacks from `poll`](https://idndx.com/2014/09/03/the-implementation-of-epoll-2/) (at `include/linux/poll.h`). Therefore, the execution time of `epoll` to receive interesting file descriptor events is O(1) in terms of number of connections *n*. However, adding, modifying, or removing file descriptors to the interest list is O(log(n)) due to the use of a red-black tree.

Why is a red-black tree used to implement the interest list when it appears that a hash table could provide O(1) performance for adding and removing connections as well as using the connections? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: Hash table is just an abstract data structure. Internally it can be implemented using self balancing trees (red black tree) to limit worst time complexity to O(log(n)). Do you have pointers to `hash table` that you are referring to in the kernel source? here's `struct eventpoll ` using red black tree in the kernel source - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/eventpoll.c#L203

Comment: I cannot speak for the kernel devs, but fwiw __a)__ a rb tree is fast enough, most people use `epoll` with just a couple of descriptors __b)__ a hash table would either waste a lot of space or degenerate into a couple of linked-lists (or whatever was used to implement its buckets) __c)__ choosing the right hash function is kind of a black magic, most people just copy it from Knuth or elsewhere (and they already managed to "hug" it up in the [past](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/4/29/838)).